# Save checkbox value and send it to e-mail

Tags: android

I want to save checkbox data from 3 pages and than send it to e-mail with button, what i did wrong there? Or maybe i'm missed something? I tried some ideas but now i'm just stuck with it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_which_drink);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    intent.setType("button/press");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"djalise@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ElBoricuaSandwich");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "../chooseDrinkSize");
}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox5:
            if (checked) ;
                //
            else
                //
                break;
        case R.id.checkBox6:
            if (checked) ;
                //
            else
                //
                break;
            //

        case R.id.checkBox7:
            if (checked) ;
                //
            else
                //
                break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: That's not a lot to work with.. Give some more details please..

Comment: heyy alisa, i think You forgot to write this line: "startActivity(intent)" at last line of "onCreate()"

Comment: first pages works fine, i just need collect checked values from pages and send it to email, but on last pages button don't work at all, and send options will popup before pressing checkbox and all sending options shows blocked

Comment: Where are your checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a method to send an email and call to this method when an action occurs

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
    private String emailText = "";
    private CheckBox box1;
    private CheckBox box2;
    private CheckBox box3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_which_drink);
        initViews();
    }

    public void sendEmail() {
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"djalise@gmail.com"});
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        Intent mailChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Title");
        startActivity(mailChooserIntent);
    }

    private void initViews(){
        box1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box1);
        box2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box2);
        box3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box3);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buildEmailText();
                sendEmail();
            }
        });
    }

    private void buildEmailText(){
        if(box1.isChecked) emailText += "\nBox 1 is checked";
        if(box2.isChecked) emailText += "\nBox 2 is checked";
        if(box3.isChecked) emailText += "\nBox 3 is checked";
    }
    //...
```

Comment: mailing is working, but is there a possibility to automate this process? and checkbox data still not saved and didn't sent, just opens gmail composer

Comment: Error:(43, 17) error: method sendEmail in class whichDrink cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Corrected, try it now.

Comment: it's ok, but how to automatically send data to e-mail? without opening gmail composer?

Comment: and how to add checkbox values from other pages to this one mail?

Comment: You have different posibilities: using SharedPreferences, using a static variable, using a local database, passing the values between activities, etc.